# Wordpress erro ao adicionar scripts no footer e estilos no header com enqueue

Tags: wordpress

Código

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');

//add_action('init', 'enqueue_scripts');
//tentei também com o init, chega a chamar as funções do functions.php e mostra algo se eu colocar o printr, mas nada dos scripts e estilos :c

 function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('css-lindo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/meu-css-lindo.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-bonito', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/que-js-bonito.js', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-mara', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/js-mara.js', array ('jquery', 'que-js-bonito'), '1.0', true); 
}
```

Sim os arquivos foram conferidos e estão no diretórios, ao ver o código fonte nada no header e footer. 
A função está sendo chamada, se eu usar o add no init e colocar um printr aparece a string.

Obrigada.

Comment: Parece que você precisa registrar o estilo ou script, de uma olhada neste método wp_register_style('my_stylesheet', plugins_url('my-stylesheet.css', __FILE__));, deve ser usado antes de wp_enqueue_script() para cada um, não vou fazer uma resposta pois não tenho certeza.

Comment: Seu arquivo de header tem a função wp_head()? e o footer tem a função: wp_footer()?

Comment: depois que eu adicionei esse wp_head e wp_footer os scripts apareceram mas os js estão printando em baixo dos css em vez de no fim da página.